# Can i control the different decimal digits output in vector in r?

Tags: r

Can i control the different  decimal digits output in vector in r?

```
> c(2.44,5)
[1] 2.44 5.00
```

if i want to get the following output format how can i do?
for the vector ,one is 2.44 ,other is 5 .

```
   2.44 5
```

it can not work for me.

```
> c(2.44,round(5,0))    
[1] 2.44 5.00
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? The other answers seem like ways to solve this as stated, but maybe `sprintf` would give you the control you want, i.e. `cat(sprintf("%.2f %.0f\n", 2.44, 5))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** 
Try this:

```
R> noquote(prettyNum(c(2.44, 5)))
[1] 2.44 5
```

---

**Previous answer:**

If you don't mind a character representation, you could do this

```
R> prettyNum(c(2.44, 5))
[1] "2.44" "5"
```

You could also make your own function

```
print.myway <- function(x, ...) { 
  for(xx in x) cat(xx, " ", sep="")
  cat("\n") 
}
print.myway(c(2.44, 5))
#2.44 5
```

Since I named that like an S3 method of the generic `print` function, any object that has a class of "myway" will be printed like that.  So, you could also use it like this

```
R> x <- c(2.44, 5)
R> class(x) <- "myway"
R> x
2.44 5
```

Comment: Cool. It doesn't break the line automatically as `print.default` does, but this should be considered a feature not a bug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: print it as a single-row matrix:

```
> t(c(2.44, 5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2.44    5
```